# How to exclude the directive's own element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, layout, angularjs-directive

### Motivation

Create a layout that directly descends the body element. The layout should wrap the `ng-view` with a scaffold template.

### Constraints

The layout template will have arbitrary content (and potentially any number of root elements, so `replace: true` will not work here).

### What have I tried

- Writing a directive that utilizes `ng-transclude` to wrap the `ng-view` with the layout structure. As `ng-transclude` interaction with `ng-view` seems is no longer supported in version 1.2, no help here.

How, than, can I still exclude the directive's element itself from the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can utilize the linking function to replace the directive's target element with the template's contents, as follows:

```js
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('scaffold', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'views/scaffold-template.html',
            restrict: 'EA',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                // exclude the directive's own element
                element.replaceWith(element.contents());
            }
        };
    });
```

This comes in handy when the template *absolutely must* have arbitrary content, or simply can't have one root element.

As this manipulation will take place in all the directive's instances regardless, it's perhaps more appropriate to use the `compile` function, but `link` seems sufficient for the proof of concept.

Comment: Why simply not use `replace: true`?

Comment: @Stewie, `replace: true` only allow for one root element. I've updated the question to depict this. thanks.

Comment: @Stewie, by the way, much to my surprise (and dismay), `replace` is nowhere to be found [in the current version's docs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/docs/guide/directive).

Comment: Directive api is described in [`$compile` service](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/docs/api/ng.$compile) in newer versions. You'll find the `replace` property there. And, why not simply wrap the `scaffold-template.html` view in simple `<div>`, and you're done?

Comment: @Stewie, just cuz i wanted the template to be 'clean'. in second thought, your solution is much simpler *and* cleaner. please add this as an answer, thank you!

Comment: @Stewie this won't solve my case after all, see my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`replace` property of the [Directive Definition Object](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile#description_comprehensive-directive-api_directive-definition-object) allows you to specify whether the directive's template will replace the host element (`{..., replace: true, ...}`) or just insert the template within (`{..., replace: false, ...}` - default setting).

So in your case you will want to set the `replace` to `true`.

One thing to note though is that your directive's template needs to have a single root DOM node, otherwise angular will throw *"Error: Template must have exactly one root element"*. (this is a [known limitation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459)).

If your directive's template looks like this:

```html
<br />
<span>{{name}}</span>
```

you will need to wrap it in single root element, as in:

```html
<span>
  <br />
  <span>{{name}}</span>
<span>
```

<sub>Note: This is needed **only** when using `replace: true`.</sub>

Comment: after trying this out i realized that this is not what i was after. though it will replace the template's element, the *directive* target element is still there, as the template is embedded within. i was looking for a way to eliminate the *directive's own element*.

Comment: Not sure I'm following you. Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qfXKflvuUQlempUQ1rvl?p=preview) demonstrating how `replace:true` replaces the _directive's own element_.

Comment: well, what i'm trying to achieve is to get rid *both of the **template root**, and the **directive's target element*** (which is `<div my-directive>Original content</div>` in the plunkr). so the template content (short its root element) will sit on the body element. perhaps [an updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fBn8O3nFrsETyZ3RdkGz?p=preview) will clarify this - here it's clearer that the injected content still has a `span` that wraps it (which is not my goal).